# Inconsistent behavior across different copies of same python version

Tags: python

I was recently playing around with the following piece of code:

```
print(getattr(__builtins__, "__import__")("random"))
```

On my local version of Python, it seemed to work as expected:

```
<module 'random' from 'C:\\Users\\lkfjsa\\Programs\\Python3.6.1\\lib\\random.py'>
```

My version is:

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Then I proceeded to try the same thing on repl.it: [Code Here](https://repl.it/KpQW/3)

The most information I could find about the version is:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
```

Which then gives this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__import__'
```

I am absolutely baffled... anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the name `__builtins__` is an implementation detail:

> As an implementation detail, most modules have the name `__builtins__` made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module [the `builtins` module] or the value of this module’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because possibly due to repl.it's sandboxing implementation or something along those lines, their version of `__builtins__` is actually a `dict`.

```
   type(__builtins__)
=> <class 'dict'>
   __builtins__['__import__']
=> <built-in function __import__>
   __builtins__['__import__']('random')
=> <module 'random' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/random.py'>
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I was wondering whether there was a way to import files without import __import__ or eval